# Double iteration doesn't generate error for dict?

Tags: python

This is a newbie question.

```
[(i,j) for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]
```

returns

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

However, why

```
{i: j for i in range(3) for j in range(3)}
```

returns

```
{0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2}
```

But it's supposed to generate the following invalid dict

```
{0: 0, 0: 1, 0: 2, 1: 0, 1: 1, 1: 2, 2: 0, 2: 1, 2: 2}
```

Comment: Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: Right. Curiously, why python allows the expression. I would rather it raises error instead of this behaving.

Comment: Why would it raise an error? Reassigning a different value to a key is a natural and common operation.

Comment: Read about Hash table data structures, and why and how they are used, starting with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: The double iteration should generate the product of two lists. Even if it generates and run dict assignment statements, what if, saying in an implementation for very large lists, the assignment statements are executed concurrently(out of order)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python *does* process the full, 9-element expression you generated with the nested comprehension.  Python processes the expression according to the rules of the data type.  Each of these elements is an assignment to the indicated dict element, roughly equivalent to

```
d = {}
d[0] = 0
d[0] = 1
d[0] = 2
d[1] = 0
d[1] = 1
d[1] = 2
d[2] = 0
d[2] = 1
d[2] = 2
```

This results in the dict you saw.  You *cannot* get a dict as you requested:

```
{0: 0, 0: 1, 0: 2, 1: 0, 1: 1, 1: 2, 2: 0, 2: 1, 2: 2}
```

as this is not a valid, sustainable `dict` value.

Python doesn't raise an error because the expression is not faulty, by language definition.  There are applications in which overwriting a key is desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Python `dict` data structure does not allow duplicate keys. Instead, in this case Python returns the last item updated.

Comment: Right. Curiously, why python allows the expression. I would rather it raises error instead of this behaving.

Comment: I completely agree with you, it should at least raise a warning, right? haha